# how to get distinct count on 13 billion records in ABINITIO

Tags: count, duplicates, distinct, ab-initio

I have 13 billion records as mfs file in abinito. I need to count distinct imsis that are grouped by date,city,district. I tried the two things coming to my mind but the operation is soo slow. How to count distinct values faster ?

1)
`length_of(vector_sort_dedup_first(accumulation( in.imsi_4g )))   in rollup having keys {date; city; district}`

2)
`PBK {date; city; district; imsi_4g} , dedup sorted having keys {date_id; city_name; district_name; imsi_max_4g}`

Answer (score 0):

Do the processing in parallel

(each thread would process five hundred million records)

```
let distinct_count = length_of(in.imsi_max_4g) in rollup keys {date, city, district} parallel 26;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Dean. I couldnot use the first option, set function was not recognized. I tried the second one then. In transform, it gets error like 'Error in line 4:
let distinct_count = length_of(in.imsi_max_4g) parallel 26;
Unexpected token: 'parallel'. '. I put the command on the transform parameter in rollup component. Am I doing something wrong ? Could you please tell me ? Thanks a lot Dean

Comment: @charmander try my updated code

Comment: is it possible for you to put an image ? I think I am doing sth wrong. Where do you put distinct count parameter ?

Comment: `distinct_count` is your output value you are looking for

Comment: so just do `length_of(in.imsi_max_4g) in rollup keys {date, city, district} parallel 26;`